# model window shows up behind the iPhones status bar

Tags: titanium

When opening a modal window, if the windows navBarHidden property is set to true, opening it the first time is fine. After open another model window within it and ,by clicking 'Back' navButton and reopening it, the modal window shows up behind the iPhones status bar at the top (where the signal, clock etc is) It seems good on Android.
Any help appreciated!!

-gangaraju

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a listener to the focus event to the first modal window and hide it when it's called.

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
win.addEventListener('focus', function(e){ win.navBarHidden = true;});
```